# Other ways to get the return values from "yield" in "async" functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, yield

When using **`async for` statement** in `async def call_test()` as shown below:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    yield "One"
    yield "Two"
    yield "Three"

async def call_test():
    async for i in test(): # Here
        print(i)

asyncio.run(call_test())
```

I could get the return values below from `yield` in `async def test()`:

```
One
Two
Three
```

Now, are there other ways like below to get the return values from `yield` in `async def test()`? and it's ok, if other ways are not like below as long as we can get the return values from `yield` in `async def test()`:

```py
# ...

async def call_test():
    x = test()
    print(next(x)) # "One"
    print(next(x)) # "Two"
    print(next(x)) # "Three"

# ...
```

```py
# ...

async def call_test():
    x = test()
    print(x.__next__()) # 'One"
    print(x.__next__()) # "Two"
    print(x.__next__()) # "Three"

# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For async generators, you have to await the built-in `anext` instead of calling `next`:

```
...
print(await anext(x))
...
```